# double to System.Windows.Media.TileBrush (ViewPort)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, media

I am writing WPF app with MVVM pattern. Somewhere in between (in ListBox) I have defined ViewPort (Short version):

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Border.Background>
            </Border.Background>

            <ScrollViewer>
                <Border>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <VisualBrush 
                            TileMode="Tile" 
                            Viewport="0,0,36,36" 
                            ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
                            Viewbox="0,0,20,20" 
                            ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

I like to change numbers of ViewPort in C# class, but numbers come from calculation with double variables. So question is how to change from double (4 numbers) to TileBrush?

I already define get/set for TileBrush:

```
private System.Windows.Media.TileBrush _gridsquaresize;
    public System.Windows.Media.TileBrush GridSquareSize
    {
        get { return _gridsquaresize; }
        set
        {
            _gridsquaresize = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GridSquareSize");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ***how to change from double (4 numbers) to TileBrush*** - where do you want to do this? in XAML or in code? Anyway it's unclear on what exactly you want regard of what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `Viewport` as follows:

```
  GridSquareSize.Viewport = new Rect(1,1,100,100);
```

see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info

Comment: Thanks! I hope for MVVM solution :) I know that is just pattern, but anyway thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I can't see any MVVM in your code, so it's hard to provide a solution